# Assets/line_genertaor.cs(9,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Line' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

Its giving error CS)246 that line could not be found are you missing an assembly reference there are 3 scripts all of them are i guess linked so what should i do i am unable to solve the error

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class line_genertaor : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject linePrefab;

    Line activeLine;

    void Update()

    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            GameObject lineGo = Instantiate(linePrefab);
            activeLine = lineGo.GetComponent<Line>();

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))

        {

            activeLine = null;

        }

        if (activeLine != null)
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            activeLine.UpdateLine (mousePos);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Add a reference to what ever namespace houses the class `Line`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it came from here: https://github.com/Brackeys/Line-Rider-Replica/blob/master/Line%20Rider%20Replica/Assets/LineCreator.cs

Then, what you are probably missing is the Line class, which was defined here: https://github.com/Brackeys/Line-Rider-Replica/blob/master/Line%20Rider%20Replica/Assets/Line.cs